# is there a way to eject all external hard drives from the command line? (OS X)

Tags: macos, command-line, applescript

Is there a way to eject all the mounted hard drive volumes on an OS X computer from the command line? Applescript is OK if I can wrap that in a shell script.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Terminal try:

- `umount -a`  *(All the filesystems described via getfsent(3) are unmounted.)*
- `umount -A`  *(All the currently mounted filesystems except the root unmounted.)*

Fore more information see `man umount`.

### Update:

Seems like you can also use this:

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk*
```

Didn't test it, though. If it doesn't work, try to use "unmount" instead of "unmountDisk".

Oh, I also found the `eject` argument (instead of `unmountDisk`). That might also be of interest.

### Update 2:

`diskutil eject /dev/*` seems what you are looking for (see comments).

Comment: Why not? Any error messages? If so, please post them here. Also did you try the "-A" option (capital A).

Comment: I tried umount -a, and a finder window opened, but that was it. I'll have to try the other commands tonight when I'm back where my external hard drives are.

Comment: `diskutil eject` also stops spinning of external HDD. `diskutil unmountDisk` keeps it spinning.

Answer (score 22):

There is another elegant way to unmount all external hard drives without knowing the exact names:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to eject (every disk whose ejectable is true)'
```

To ignore network mounts and optical disks, use:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to eject (every disk whose ejectable is true and local volume is true and free space is not equal to 0)'
```

Comment: This is probably the most correct way to do it, even though the syntax is horrific.

Comment: Nice one. I just needed to eject my TM drive so went with `on run {input, parameters}
 tell application "Finder" to eject (every disk whose name is "[tm drive name]")
end run`

Answer (score 5):

I found this to work for ejecting all dmg and physical hard drives:

```
find /dev -name "disk[1-9]" -exec diskutil eject {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `diskutil eject /dev/disk2` or whatever your device number is you want to eject.  That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

```
df | grep Volumes | awk '{ print $1 }' | while read disk; do diskutil unmount "$disk"; done
```