# How to mount all mountable external disks (macOS)

Tags: macos, terminal, mount

I frequently use this Terminal command to mount all my connected external disks:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to eject (every disk whose ejectable is true)'
```

It works well.  But I wondered if there was a 'reverse' command, that would mount all mountable external disks?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049838/1135424

Comment: Mount, not unmount

Comment: probably `diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk*` ?

Comment: That returns `Usage:   diskutil mountDisk DiskIdentifier|DeviceNode
Attempt to mount the directly-mountable volumes on all of a whole disk's partitions. However, virtual volumes which are implied by e.g. Core Storage Physical Volumes, AppleRAID Members, etc. are not handled. If you specify a partition, then that partition's whole-disk parent is assumed.`